# checking if character is upper or lower case in alphanumeric

Tags: c, char, uppercase

I have this C code. If I input a LOL123 it should display that it is uppercase. And lol123 it is in lowercase. How do I use isalpha in excluding non-numerical input when checking isupper or is lower?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 6
char input[50];
int my_isupper(char string[]);

int main(){
    char input[] = "LOL123";
    int m;

    m= isupper(input);
    if( m==1){
        printf("%s is all uppercase.\n", input);
    }else
        printf("%s is not all uppercase.\n", input);

    return 0;
}

int my_isupper(char string[]){
    int a,d;

    for (a=0; a<SIZE); a++){
        d= isupper(string[a]) ; 
    }

    if(d != 0)
        d=1;

    return d;
}
```

Comment: What about Lol123, loL123, lOl123 ...

Comment: Based on the prints in the code, those would all be considered not uppercase. The asker seems to care if a word is all upper case or not.

Comment: `a<sizeof(string)` is wrong. you could use `for (a=0; string[a] ; a++) {` instead.

Comment: Your if statement `if (isupper(input) == 1) ...` is not correct. The `is...` functions (and most true/false functions in general) may return any nonzero value to indicate truth. The correct way is `if (isupper(foo)) { ... } ` or `if (!isupper(foo)) { ... } `

Comment: @rullof LOl123 should be considered not all uppercase.

Comment: The name `isupper` is already used by the standard function, that you are trying to use inside your own code. Since C has no function overloading this can never work. If you are compiling your code with a decent level of warnings, your compiler should cry at you.

Comment: The `ctype.h` api also all take `int` as a formal parameter, so unless you've no plans for dealing with high-asci (and torque the europeans in the process), you should be casting those `char` values to `unsigned int` to avoid a sign-extension.

Comment: @Brandin the function will not return 1 even if I set it to 'if(d!=0)', d=1, and return d?

Comment: @honmayanranger Delete your isupper definition and use the one in ctype. If you want to make your own version, name it something else like `my_isupper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For upper-case function just loop trough the string and if a lowercase character is encountred you return `false` like value. And don't use standard library functions names to name your own functions. Use `isUpperCase` instead.

Live Demo: https://eval.in/93429

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isUpperCase(const char *inputString);

int main(void)
{
    char inputString1[] = "LOL123";
    char inputString2[] = "lol123";
    printf("%s is %s\n", inputString1, isUpperCase(inputString1)?"upper-case":"not upper-case");
    printf("%s is %s\n", inputString2, isUpperCase(inputString2)?"lower-case":"not upper-case");
    return 0;
}

int isUpperCase(const char *inputString)
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(inputString);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputString[i] >= 'a' && inputString[i] <= 'z') {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Note: The standard makes no warrants about the *sequential* property of characters numeric-eval *except* `'0'...'9'`. While this will "work" on ascii platforms (and even EBCDIC) it isn't by the standard.

Comment: So, there is no way of finding if an input is all uppercase or lowercase using only isalpha(), islower(), and isupper()?

Answer (score 2):

```
int my_isalpha_lower(int c) {
    return ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')); } 

int my_isalpha_upper(int c) {
        return ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')); } 

int isdigit(int c) {
        return (c >= '0' && c <= '9'); }



while (*s) {

     if (!is_digit(*s) && !my_isalpha_lower(*s)) 
     {
         //isnot lower but is alpha 
     }
     else if (!is_digit(*s) && !my_alpha_upper(*s))
     {
        //is not upper but is alpha 
     }

     s++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char c = ...;
if (isalpha(c))
{ 
     // do stuff if it's alpha
} else {
     // do stuff when not alpha
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot to learn, besides using a name of a standard function your design also is completely flawed. You only memorize the case of the last character that you encounter in your `for` loop, so the result that you return is not at all what you think.

Some more observations:

- Don't use the name of a standard function for your own.
- Arrays decay to pointers when then are used as function parameters. You have no way to automatically detect the size of the array.
- You expect your return from `isupper` to be a logical value. Testing that again with `==1` makes not much sense.
- You have two different variables called `input`, one in file scope, one in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple:

```
#include <ctype.h>

/**
 * Will return true if there's at least one alpha character in 
 * the input string *and* all alpha characters are uppercase.
 */
int allUpper( const char *str )
{
  int foundAlpha = 0;                   
  int upper = 1;

  for ( const char *p = str; *p; p++ )
  {
    int alpha = isalpha( *p );           
    foundAlpha = foundAlpha || alpha;    
    if ( alpha )
      upper = upper && isupper( *p );    
  } 

  return foundAlpha && upper; 
}
```