# scanf read variable number of characters

Tags: c

I was wondering how I can get `scanf` to skip reading a character if I press enter... My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int a, status;
    char b;
    printf("Please enter a positive number immediately"
           "followed by at  most one lower-case letter:\n\n");
    status = scanf("%i%c", &a, &b);
    if (status == 1 && getchar() == '\n') {
        printf("\nThank you!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter just a number and nothing else, I need to press enter again to trigger the `%c`, `&b` in `scanf`. How do I avoid that and get the program to accept just 1 number to jump to the `printf`?
I tried:

```
if (status == 1 && getchar() == '\n')
```

but that won't work.

Comment: I suggest using `fgets` to read a whole line, and then use `sscanf` to convert the number, if any, at the beginning of the line.

Comment: If `scanf("%i%c"...)` is successful it will return `2`, not `1`. `fgets` would make more sense here.

Comment: Well I only just started programming, so I'm not familiar with fgets. How would I use it in this context? Could you post me the line?

Comment: If you added a line: `printf("%d [%c] = %d\n", a, b, status);` after the `scanf()`, doing a debug print of what was given, and if you typed `31` as the number, then you'd see `31 [` on one line, and `] = 2` on the next, because the `%c` would read the newline as the character, and because the `scanf()` as a whole would return 2 because it successfully converted two values.  If you used `"%i%[a-z]"` as the format string, then you'd get 1 returned in `status` and 31 in `a` and garbage in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your best course of action is to use `fgets` to just read in a string, then parse and validate it. [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919009/how-to-read-from-stdin-with-fgets) will provide you with enough resources for you to educate yourself about the use of `fgets`.

Here is one approach you can take. Please note that this code does not attempt to validate every possible input a user can provide, but rather give you a reasonable direction you can take to solve your problem if the input is assumed correct. I will leave the task of validation to you. The code below should provide enough tools to accomplish the rest of your task. Look at using a `for` loop to step through the `buffer` and ensure the input is correct. Use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` to test each character. You can also implement your own functions to test each character as is done
in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21288988/7159784).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for atoi() 
#include <string.h> //for strlen() 
#include <ctype.h> //for isalpha()
#define MAX_INPUTLENGTH 500
int main(void)
{
    //Always a good idea to initialize variables to avoid Undefined Behaviour!
    char buffer[MAX_INPUTLENGTH] = { '\0' };
    int a = 0, status = 1, length = 0;
    char b = '\0';

    printf("Please enter a positive number immediately"
        "followed by at  most one lower-case letter:\n\n");

    //this gets you a string you can work with
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    length = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[length - 1] = '\0';//remove the trailing '\n'
    length--;

    //now see if last character is a letter
    if (isalpha(buffer[length - 1])) {
        b = buffer[length - 1];//then assign and..
        buffer[length - 1] = '\0';//trim the letter
    }

    //this function converts the remaining string to an int
    a = atoi(buffer);

    //Use the debugger and observe how these functions work in order
    //to validate the input. for now, status is always 1!
    if (status == 1) {
        printf("\nThank you!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As noted in the comments below by @Jonathan, to portably get the count of an array, one should use `sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])`. Since you are using a `char[]`, `sizeof(buffer[0])` evaluates to `1`, thus can be omitted when calling `fgets`.

Comment: Note that `_countof()` is a MS-specific feature.  It isn't entirely appropriate here; using `sizeof()` is both portable and correct.  The value returned by `_countof()` is the same as the value from `sizeof()` in this case because `sizeof(buffer[0]) == 1`.

Comment: Also note that your logic won't be upset by the user typing `31 ants`; it will happily treat the `s` as the 'one lower-case letter' (because the buffer is only 10 characters long, if you entered `31 elephants`, you'd leave the `t` and the `s` and the newline unread; if you typed `2000000000a`, you'd leave the `a` unread).  You also need both `<string.h>` (for `strlen()`) and `<stdlib.h>` (for `atoi()`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thank you for your comments. I made edits to my answer accordingly. This feedback is very much appreciated, as I am still relatively new to SO and still learning how to give the best answers. People like you will help me get there quicker!